# Using Spring DI in a library

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a package that would be used as a dependency in an application. Thus, my package is NOT the executable application.

I have a class `Foo` that has some dependencies. I want to be able to do something like:

```
public class Foo {
  @Autowired
  Bar bar;

  @Autowired
  Player player

  ... many other dependencies like this

}
```

In above, `Bar`, `Player` etc. are all interfaces and I have implemented concrete classes like:

```
public class BarOne implements Bar {
}

public class BarTwo implements Bar {
}
```

I want Spring to instantiate the *correct implementation depending on a `Config` and this `Config` will NOT come from `application.properties`*. Remember I am developing a package meant to be used as a library. The application using this library may create multiple instances of `Foo` with different configs. So the application may use the library like:

```
Foo fooOne = FooFactory.create(config1);
Foo fooTwo = FooFactory.create(config2);
```

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this or is Spring not the right tool for this? I can use any DI Framework - doesn't have to be Spring.

Answer (score 0):

A Spring library isn’t an issue, and one of the most common ways is to create a starter package that uses auto configuration. See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter) and [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.11.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html).

However, Your client app has can’t be creating `Foo` instances manually, because the beans have to be created and managed by Spring. If the structure/schema of config is predefined, you can provide a parser with your library that is capable of reading a config file, similar to what spring does with `application.properties`, and creates `Foo` instances. The client app has to be a Spring application in order to use your Spring library.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering the encapsulation of attributes, you need to think about it yourself. In fact, there are many solutions, which are nothing more than dynamically passing some values ​​based on config and then generating instances.

Of course, you can also implement the singleton pattern yourself.
Or, in create, directly use if-else to judge the incoming string to instantiate the bar object.

The output of the code below is this:

```
BarOne
BarTwo
```

The following is the code. There is no logic written. It is a simple implementation.

```
package com;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.className = "com.BarOne";
        config.aClass = BarOne.class;

        Foo foo = FooFactory.create(config);

        foo.whatIsTheBar();

        config.className = "com.BarTwo";
        config.aClass = BarTwo.class;

        foo = FooFactory.create(config);

        foo.whatIsTheBar();
    }
}

class Config {
    public String className;
    public Class<? extends Bar> aClass;
}

class FooFactory {
    public static Foo create(Config config) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(config.className);
        return new Foo(config.aClass.cast(c.newInstance()));
    }
}

class Foo {
    private Bar bar;
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void whatIsTheBar() {
        bar.show();
    }
}

interface Bar {
    void show();
}

class BarOne implements Bar {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("BarOne");
    }
}

class BarTwo implements Bar {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("BarTwo");
    }
}
```